# Select previous input jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with many input=text and I have neraby two image (-,+) I want to increase or decrease the previous input text. I don't want to put into the input text an id because I can have a lot of this line with input text and minus or plus.
With my code the minus button works but the plus button not why?

My jQuery code

```
$('.minus').click(function(){
        var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
        var floatRegex = /^((\d+(\.\d *)?)|((\d*\.)?\d+))$/;

        var num = $(this).prev('input').val();
        if(intRegex.test(num) || floatRegex.test(num)) {
            if (num>0){
                $(this).prev('input').val(num-1);
            }
        }
        else{
            //non è un numero
        }

    });

    $('.plus').click(function(){
        var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
        var floatRegex = /^((\d+(\.\d *)?)|((\d*\.)?\d+))$/;

        var num = $(this).prev.prev('input').val();
        if(intRegex.test(num) || floatRegex.test(num)) {
                $(this).prev.prev('input').val(num+1);
        }
        else{
            //non è un numero
        }

    });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="qta" id="qta" style="width:50px;"/>
                            <img src="img/shop/meno.jpg" alt="" class="minus" style="cursor:pointer"/>
                            <img src="img/shop/piu.png" alt="" class="plus" style="cursor:pointer"/>
```

Comment: First of all, it doesn't work because **IDs of elements should be unique**. If you have multiple input elements and plus/minus images, you should consider using classes instead.

Comment: edited with class instead of id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var num = $(this).prev().prev('input').val();
```

and

```
$(this).prev().prev('input').val(num+1);
```

You missed a `()` twice

anyway I would wrap every input and images in their own wrapper and I would find the input with `$(this).parent().find('input')`

Answer (score 1):

use this to go previous

```
 var num = $(this).prev().prev('input').val();
```

if you want to go next  use this

```
 var num = $(this).next().next('input').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have only one input , you can use the  ID of that input

```
$('#qta').val(num+1)
```

and

```
$('#qta').val(num-1)
```